# Service stopForeground(false) remove notification when should not

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

Instead of

> stopForeground(true)

calling,

> stopForeground(false)

should retain the notification as it is (without ongoing state) unless it is dismissed by user/removed programmatically.
This also should prevents notification flashing since I am not recreating the notification.

But it does not work. stopForeground(false) has the same behavior of stopForeground(true).

This is a sample project:

```
public class AudioTestService extends Service {
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "TestChannel";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 14;
Notification mBuilder;

public AudioTestService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopForeground(true);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent intentA = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentA, 0);

    Notification mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Titolo")
            .setContentText("Descrizione")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build();
    this.mBuilder = mBuilder;
    createNotificationChannel();
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder);

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = CHANNEL_ID;
        String description = CHANNEL_ID + "Description ";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(false);
    //NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder);
    super.onDestroy();
} }
```

The activity, easily handle the button click event:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startService = findViewById(R.id.startService);
    Button stopService = findViewById(R.id.stopService);
    Button stopNotification = findViewById(R.id.stopWithNotification);

    startService.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopService.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopNotification.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startService:
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, AudioTestService.class));
            break;
        case R.id.stopService:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.stopWithNotification:
            stopService(new Intent(this, AudioTestService.class));
            break;
    }
}}
```

If you look at the Service's onDestroy() method I set

> stopForeground(false);

instead of the method onTaskRemoved() that should remove the notification when the app is cleaned from the task list.

What am I doing wrong?

Please do not mark this as duplicated, I am looking for a solution for days...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `stopForeground(false);` from `onDestroy()`, send a broadcast from activity (with action) for stop service. Change your `onStartCommand` code to check action in `intent` and do `startForeground` or `stopForeground(false);`

Comment: ...Thanks for your advice.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, I also had this problem. It seems that if `stopForeground(false)` is called in `onDestroy()` then the notification still gets removed. So `stopForeground(false)` must be called at an earlier point in time.